# How to sort and keep the integrity of the list?

Tags: python, sorting

So I have a minor issue with a script I'm writing. I have a text file that looks something like:

```
'20 zebra 12 bear'
```

That's just an example, the format is 1 line all items separated by spaces. The script works to sort them out and do a couple of other things to the strings but what I can't figure out is how to keep it set the way it is. For example the above line should sort like this:

```
12
bear
20
zebra
```

I need to keep a number in the number place and a string in a strings place but they should be sorted alphanumerically.
Here is my script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Make sure you use the proper modules.
import sys, string

# This area defines the arguments and returns a usage message should it be used incorrectly.
try:
  infilename = sys.argv[1]; outfilename = sys.argv[2]
except:
  print "Usage:",sys.argv[0], "infile outfile"; sys.exit(1)

ifile = open(infilename, 'r') # Opens the input file for reading
ofile = open(outfilename, 'w') # Opens the output file for writing
data = ifile.readlines()[0].split() # Reads the lines on the input file

# The items in the list are sorted here and defined by a space.
sort = sorted(data, key=lambda item: (int(item.partition(' ')[0])
                                   if item[0].isdigit() else float('inf'), item))

# Use this to remove any special characters in the list
filtered = [s.translate(None, string.punctuation) for s in sort]


ofile.write('\n'.join(filtered)) # Writes the final output to file (one on each line)



ifile.close() # Closes the input file
ofile.close() # Closes the output file
```

I know it's not the prettiest but I haven't been using Python long so if you have suggestions on how to make it prettier, I'm all ears. All I really need is to keep a number a number and a string a string but swap them around to sort. Thanks for any assistance given.

Comment: For clarification: you want "20 zebra 12 bear" to become "12 bear 20 zebra".  What do you want "20 bear 12 zebra" to do?  Stay the same, or become "12 bear 20 zebra"?  IOW, are these pairs like "(20,bear), (12, zebra)` to be sorted by either the number or the name, or just a bunch of separate numbers and names intermixed?

Comment: Yes, I want it to become 12 bear 20 zebra. They are only separated by spaces. The data should stay in the same format it's in.

Comment: Edit your question and add more examples and an explanation of your sort criteria.

Comment: @Oz123: Don't change someone's input format in edits.  It's his file, not yours.

Comment: and @Oz123, don't give someone a -1 just because you're a grammar Nazzi. Seriously? Didn't even bother to try to answer the question.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to interleave numbers and strings?

Comment: @nneonneo I am not sure what you mean. As I have said, if the format is '3 2 1' it should end up '1 2 3'. If it's 'bear 2 apple 1' it should end up as 'apple 1 bear 2'. So far the script does very well with sorting everything out. The only problem is that it sorts everything as '1 2 apple bear'. I hope that clears things up. Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: @user1675042: respectfully, you haven't said "3 2 1" should become "1 2 3".  Your examples have always been number-word-number-word, and if they're *not* number-word, then (e.g.) Ashwini's solution will break.

Comment: @DSM Thank you. I was simply trying to make things easier to understand. Yes, they are number and string combinations.

Comment: So, interleaved pairs, then? Please make that clear...

Comment: @nneonneo Yes. Number and letter combinations. A number should remain a number and a word should remain a word. Thank you.

Comment: No, what I mean is do you always follow a number with a word, and a word with a number? See my answer...

Comment: @user1675042, I did not vote your question down, although it was vague. I seldom vote down people.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks to everyone who helped me out. I'm a noob and it's good to know that people here are willing to help me understand all of this. I typically use VBS but am branching out to the other ones. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really weird question.

```
def strange_sort(seq):
    """
    Sorts digitstrings (by integer value) and non-digitstrings in a
    sequence among themselves, preserving the original ds/non-ds
    signature.
    """
    numbers = iter(sorted((elem for elem in seq if elem.isdigit()), key=int))
    words = iter(sorted(elem for elem in seq if not elem.isdigit()))
    final = [next(numbers if elem.isdigit() else words) for elem in seq]
    return final
```

which gives

```
>>> strange_sort("1 2 3".split())
['1', '2', '3']
>>> strange_sort("1 2 10 3".split())
['1', '2', '3', '10']
>>> strange_sort("1 2 10 3 bear".split())
['1', '2', '3', '10', 'bear']
>>> strange_sort("2 1 bear 10 3".split())
['1', '2', 'bear', '3', '10']
>>> strange_sort("2 1 zebra 10 3 bear".split())
['1', '2', 'bear', '3', '10', 'zebra']
>>> strange_sort("20 zebra 12 bear".split())
['12', 'bear', '20', 'zebra']
>>> strange_sort("20 zebra 12 bear 3".split())
['3', 'bear', '12', 'zebra', '20']
```

Actually, this is basically @przemo_li's suggestion worked out.

[edited to keep everything a string]

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create 3rd list. With 1 for number and 2 for string.

So your example would be

1, 2, 1, 2.

Than you put all numbers in one list, and strings in second. Sort them.

Than you replace each 1 in 3rd string with next number and each 2 with next string.

It should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of interleaved numbers and strings, use list slicing:

```
text = '20 zebra 12 bear 5 moose'
arr = text.split()
arr[::2] = sorted(arr[::2], key=int)
arr[1::2] = sorted(arr[1::2])

print ' '.join(arr)
```

Output:

```
5 bear 12 moose 20 zebra
```

---

For the general case, where the content might not be perfectly interleaved (e.g. '20 15 zebra 12 17 cow bear'), you can use Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

text = '20 15 zebra 12 17 cow bear 5 2 1'
arr = np.char.array(text.split())
nums = arr.isdigit()
strs = ~nums
arr[nums] = sorted(arr[nums], key=int)
arr[strs] = np.sort(arr[strs])

print ' '.join(arr)
```

Output:

```
1 2 bear 5 12 cow zebra 15 17 20
```

Comment: Thanks @nneonneo I'm going to give this a go. In reference to my script, how about with a text file? Can the char.array be used with a file?

Comment: `char.array` works on a list of strings, so I pass in `text.split()` to split the text into pieces. You can get the first line of your file with `f.readline().strip()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like so:

- Split the list into tokens, for instance using `re.split`.
- Use list slicing to create a list of the keys (numbers), and a list of the values (words).
- Sort this list of tuples. (This will sort them correctly)

If you then need it back to a string:

- Join the elements of the tuples with spaces.
- Join the resulting list with spaces.

Here's the code that does this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

data = "12 foo 35 bar 10 baz 23 foobar"

d = re.split("\s+", data)
tuples = zip(d[0::2], d[1::2])
tuples.sort()

# If you need it back to a string
dsorted = [x + " " + y for (x, y) in tuples]
datasorted = " ".join(dsorted)

print data
print datasorted
```

This outputs the following:

```
12 foo 35 bar 10 baz 23 foobar
10 baz 12 foo 23 foobar 35 bar
```